# show/hide a div based on click in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `chatbubble` that when clicked, I want it to disappear and a chat window should come up.

The chat window is the `wrapper` div. I set it `display = 'none'` in the html code below. Then in the `onclick` of `chatBubble` I show the `wrapper` div using jQuery

So initially I shouldn't see the chat window. But I see it. Also when I click on the chatbubble, I get error `Uncaught TypeError: "#wrapper".show is not a function`. What am I missing?

```
<div id = "chatBubble"  class="talk-bubble tri-right btm-right round">
     <div class="talktext">
        <p>Hi, can I help?</p>
     </div>
</div>

<div id="wrapper" display = 'none'>
    <div id="menu">
        <p class="welcome">Welcome<b></b></p>
        <p class="logout"><a id="exit" href="#">Exit</a></p>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>

   <div id="chatbox"></div>

   <form name="message" action="">
      <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
      <input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Relevant portion of javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#chatBubble").click(function(){
    //console.log("clicked")
    ('#wrapper').show();
  })
});
```

Please suggest.

Comment: You are missing the `$`: `('#wrapper').show();` should be `$('#wrapper').show();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the style property in the wrong way. You have to set it through style attribute. `show()` is a jQuery function and you are missing that just before `('#wrapper').show();` which leads to the error.

Try the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#chatBubble").click(function(){
    //console.log("clicked")
    $('#wrapper').show();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "chatBubble"  class="talk-bubble tri-right btm-right round">
     <div class="talktext">
        <p>Hi, can I help?</p>
     </div>
</div>

<div id="wrapper" style='display:none'>
    <div id="menu">
        <p class="welcome">Welcome<b></b></p>
        <p class="logout"><a id="exit" href="#">Exit</a></p>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>

   <div id="chatbox"></div>

   <form name="message" action="">
      <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
      <input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" />
  </form>
</div>
```